# Making a menu in Python

Tags: python, dictionary, menu

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Calling a function from a string with the function's name in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3061/calling-a-function-from-a-string-with-the-functions-name-in-python)

I think I could write some terrible code that would do this, but I'd much rather see the 'clean version'.

What seems the good approach to me, is to make a dict that holds the various functions that a given object can use.  Then when the user is instructed to tell the object what it's doing, it spits out a menu based on that dict.

I searched around a bit and didn't really see something that applied to me so I figured I'd give it a try.  Well, it didn't work.

```
class Man(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.cmds = ['foo', 'bar']

    def foo(self):
        print "Foo called."

    def bar(self):
        print "Bar called."

    def junk(self):
        print "Junk called." ##not in dict, on purpose, will explain

    def menu(self):
        while True:
            print "List of actions:"
            for acts in self.cmds:
                print acts
            cmd = raw_input("> ")
            if cmd in self.cmds:
                cmd()    ##doesn't work.
                         ##neither did self.cmd() (got AttributeError, obviously)

                result = getattr(self, cmd)() ## this works! thanks cdhowie
            else:
                pass

Stick = Man()
Stick.menu()
```

In case it isn't obvious, the program gives TypeError whenever I enter something which the if-else sees to be True - in this case, entering either 'foo' or 'bar'.
Here's the thing, is that I know I could just write a big long ugly if-else thing here and make this example work - but I want to be able to just append/remove from self.cmds to alter the object's functionality.  Hence the third function Junk(); Stick can't access 'Junk()' from the current dict-menu, but with a little self.cmds.append action I want it to be able to.

Freaking Python, how do they work?  Is this the right way to go about this, or is there a simpler method?

EDIT: My answer was found in the magic of getattr.  Thanks cdhowie.  The trick was to change the while loop to have this bit:   result = getattr(self, cmd)()

I know now my next mission is to finally figure out what getattr() actually does.  Forgive my noob status, heh, I know not what I code :)

FINAL EDIT: while cdhowie's example works with the original program, I have since found that ders' answer allows me to do things functionally that I wouldn't have been able to do with getattr(); ders' solution made it easier for me to use functions in other objects in Man's **init** - I think that's called 'object composition' right?  At any rate getattr() would AttributeError any functions added to self.cmds from anywhere but Man.  Or I could just be doing it weird again.  But suffice to say, ders FTW.

Comment: [This question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3061/calling-a-function-from-a-string-with-the-functions-name-in-python) is relevant if you want to call a method by name.

Comment: Ooh, that *does* do the trick.  Quick 'n easy answer, thanks a mint.

Comment: Did you edit your question with a code update that solves your problem?  If so, this Q needs to be deleted or closed.

Comment: Yes I agree.  Since I'm a new user apparently I can't answer my own question for another...7 hours.  So yeah.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your example Man.cmds is a list not a dictionary. So they TypeError is raised when the string in the self.cmds list is called as a function.

Create a dictionary with the function name as a string paired with the function itself.

```
    def __init__(self):
        self.cmds = {'foo':self.foo, 'bar':self.bar}
```

Within your Menu function, check if the user has entered in a valid function name. If so pull it out of the dictionary and call it.

```
            if cmd in self.cmds:
                command = self.cmds[cmd]
                command()
            else:
                pass
```

To dynamically add the junk function, you could then `update` cmds:

```
Stick.cmds.update({'junk':Stick.junk})
```

Comment: *This* answer took me down the path I needed, actually.  Awesome.  Thanks.

Comment: Don't use `update` to add a single item to `Stick.cmds`, just use `Stick.cmds['junk'] = Stick.junk`.